# SQL developer spool to txt row

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a bat file that calls sql developer and spool out a query to a text file, however the result is all in one row, it seems it doesn't know how to identify a row.

For example, if I run the spool script in sql developer manually, the txt file looks perfect like this:

> "Item","Qty","Price"
>
> "A11","4","0.86"
>
> "A12","3","0.56"
>
> "A14","5","0.3"

But if I ran it with the bat file, it came out like this:

> "Item","Qty","Price""A11","4","0.86""A12","3","0.56""A14","5","0.3"

Without the right format, when I import it to excel file, all the data are just in one cell.

I have tried all kinds of format like `SET PAGESIZE, SET TERMOUT`...but none of these work. In my another device I ran exactly the same code, and I do not have this problem.

bat file code:

```
@echo off

C:

cd C:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin

sdcli migration -actions=mkconn,runsql -connDetails=target_oracle:oracle:XXXXX -conn=target_oracle -sql="C:\Desktop\1.sql"
```

1.sql:

```
spool "C:\Desktop\test.txt"
@C:\2.sql as script(F5);
spool off
```

2.sql:

```
Select /*csv*/ * From (
select * from item
);
```

I got stuck here for a while, if you have solution please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can try playing also with `SET TRIMSPOOL ON`  or `OFF` to see if it makes any difference

Comment: Hi @funkyjelly Thank you so much for the reply! I have tried in the scripts however it's still not working.

Comment: Use sqcl, not sdsql - much faster and lightweight, plus it's designed to do what you want

Comment: Can you also try with `set heading on`

Comment: @funkyjelly sorry this is still not working...

Comment: @thatjeffsmith hi, thank you for the reply, could you tell me which part of the code should I change? I have googled but couldn't find much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the right SQL Developer command line interface for the job.

We have two:

**SDCLI** - this is a headless version of the full SQL Developer program - fancy way of saying, no GUI. It can do things like perform a database export or invoke a Cart feature. Using it to run a SQL statement via the Migration task is like using a flamethrower to defrost your car's windshield - although probably not nearly as fun.

**SQLcl** - this is a command-line, interactive interface to the Oracle database. It's a java based version of SQL*Plus. It has the same code as SQL Developer when it comes to making connections, running scripts, etc - but it's only 20MB vs 200+MB, and it only need a JRE vs a JDK.

Both of these programs are in your sqldeveloper\bin folder - [but SQLcl is also a separate, standalone, supported product](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html).

So, to do what you want, you need to change this:

```
sdcli migration -actions=mkconn,runsql -connDetails=target_oracle:oracle:XXXXX -conn=target_oracle -sql="C:\Desktop\1.sql"
```

to this:

sql user/pwd@server:port/service @c:\users\jdsmith\desktop\1.sql

And your 1.sql can be this:

```
spool c:\users\jdsmith\desktop\locations-so.csv
Select /*csv*/ * From locations;
spool off
exit
```

Which gives us this

[image]

Bonus: SQLcl will run through this MUCH faster.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have solved my problem perfectly!